# how to install PCL on ubuntu

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,everyone
i don't know how to install the pcl,someone knows?
please help me ,THANKS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47920/how-to-install-pcl-on-ubuntu/) by [zq07075335](https://answers.ros.org/users/3556/zq07075335/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-09**:
Did you install ROS? Or merely want to install PCL on ubuntu? According to your question I can only suggest you this: http://pointclouds.org/downloads/

**Comment by [zq07075335](https://answers.ros.org/users/3556/zq07075335/) on 2012-11-09**:
Yeah,i installed ROS,and downloaded the PCL 1.6.0 version,unpacked it ,but then i don't know how to install,some nodes? thank you

**Comment by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on 2021-10-20**:
https://pointclouds.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The stand-alone PCL is not the version that works with ROS. On Ubuntu, you can install the correct version directly from the ROS repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pcl
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-08**:
hi joq, I installed standalone pcl 1.6(prebuilt binaries)but /opt/ros/fuerte/include directory i see a folder called pcl-1.5... and in my package when i make it, i get an error vtkImageViewer.h not found....should i uninstall pcl1.6 and install pcl1.5?? a more detailed question in my accountHELP PLS

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-26**:
Is this a binary version? Can I install by catkin?